# I need a validation rule for below requirement

Tags: validation

I need a validation rule for = If values in  multiselect picklist matches any of the values on the  multiselect picklist then it should not allow to save

Comment: You need to use the combination of condition/decision making functions with INCLUDES  function on validation rule. I suggest you to read the documents,give it a try and come up with the issues/difficulties faced, so that we can assist you.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, are you saying that if any value has been selected from the multiselect picklist, then validation rule should prevent a save? If so, you can just use NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(*fieldname*))) as the criteria..

Comment: its like= If values in <object1> multiselect picklist matches any of the values on the <object2> multiselect picklist then show error message on <object1>s field

Comment: Are these objects related ? Please update the question with more info rather than commenting, that will make it easier to understand.

Comment: yes they are related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to ensure you do not have the same values in two separate multipicklists, you will need to use a trigger vs. a validation rule. I would recommend creating a trigger before update/insert that compares the values and adds the error.

Update: Suggested approach...

1. Create a set of the values from both fields
2. Iterate through the second set to check if the first set contains the value
3. Break the loop if step 2 is ever true and add error

Answer (score 0):

solution for the above question was to implement a trigger on events

using SET 's to store the multiselect picklist field and compare them with another fields data

IF it contains one of the value then use

field_Name.adderror(''); where field_Name
 is the location of error to be displayed